# Loop through XML and only "look" at specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, xml, loops, api-eveonline

in my mysql database I have several rows each containing an item id. What I would like to do is update each of the "placidRate" columns for what is contained within the XML document of the very large URL below. Example, for typeID 1230, it should find the rate of 1230 in my db and match it with the rate of `$type->sell->min`. That is the end goal. Right now all I'm looking for it to do is echo the old rate (db) and the new rate (xml) next to each other.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $oldTypeID = $row['typeID'];

    $urlPlacid = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=1230&typeid=17470&typeid=17471&typeid=1228&typeid=17463&typeid=17464&typeid=1224&typeid=17459&typeid=18&typeid=17455&typeid=17456&typeid=1227&typeid=17867&typeid=17868&typeid=20&typeid=17452&typeid=17453&typeid=1226&typeid=17448&typeid=17449&typeid=1231&typeid=17444&typeid=17445&typeid=21&typeid=17440&typeid=17441&typeid=1229&typeid=17865&typeid=17866&typeid=1232&typeid=17436&typeid=17437&typeid=19&typeid=17466&typeid=17467&typeid=1225&typeid=17432&typeid=17433&typeid=1223&typeid=17428&typeid=17429&typeid=22&typeid=17425&typeid=17426&typeid=11396&typeid=17869&typeid=17870&typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=40&typeid=39&typeid=11399&regionlimit=10000048';
    $xmlPlacid = simplexml_load_file($urlPlacid);
    foreach($xmlPlacid->marketstat->type as $type){
         $newRate = $type->sell->min;
         if($type[id] = $oldTypeID){
               echo "old placid rate: ".$row['placidRate']." || new placid rate: ".$newRate;
         }
    else{}
```

The problem with this code, is that it returns

old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 12.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 25.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 17.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 25.21old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 22.01old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 30.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 55.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 80.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 85.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 94.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 90.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 120.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 290.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 1087.06old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 4.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 10.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 40.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 143.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 819.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 2599.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 770.00old placid rate: 14.5 || new placid rate: 0.00

And I'm not entirely sure why...

One step closer to updating the sql table. edited once more

```
$market = new eveCentral();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $oldTypeID = $row['typeID'];
    $oldRate = $row['placidRate'];
    $newPlacidRate = $market->placidMin($oldTypeID);
    $newForgeRate = $market->forgeMin($oldTypeID);
    $newUniverseRate = $market->universeMin($oldTypeID);

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE itemRates SET placidRate = $newPlacidRate, forgeRate = $newForgeRate, universeRate = $newUniverseRate WHERE typeID = $oldTypeID";
```

Comment: @Gordon edited for the issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem with the wrong operator in the `if` comparison (as @GBD has outlined), you have a few issues here:

1. You are fetching the XML from eve-central.com  *for each database result row*. But the XML does not change. Move it *above* the database `while` query.
2. As @Alex has answered, use xpath to locate the item with the ID you're looking for.

A view from above:

```
$marketstat = new EveCentralMarketstat();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $oldTypeID = $row['typeID'];
    $oldRate   = $row['placidRate'];
    $newRate   = $marketstat->getSellMinByType($oldTypeID);
    if (FALSE !== $newRate) {
        echo "old placid rate: " . $oldRate . " || new placid rate: " . $newRate;
    }
}
```

Definition for the `EveCentralMarketstat` class:

*Add the functions you need for more data access, also the constructor can be improved depending on which information you need, just a quick outline how you can improve.*

```
/**
 * Wrapper Class for Even Central API Market Statistics
 */
class EveCentralMarketstat
{
    /**
     * @var SimpleXMLElement
     */
    private $xml;

    public function __construct() {

        $urlPlacid = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=1230&typeid=17470&typeid=17471&typeid=1228&typeid=17463&typeid=17464&typeid=1224&typeid=17459&typeid=18&typeid=17455&typeid=17456&typeid=1227&typeid=17867&typeid=17868&typeid=20&typeid=17452&typeid=17453&typeid=1226&typeid=17448&typeid=17449&typeid=1231&typeid=17444&typeid=17445&typeid=21&typeid=17440&typeid=17441&typeid=1229&typeid=17865&typeid=17866&typeid=1232&typeid=17436&typeid=17437&typeid=19&typeid=17466&typeid=17467&typeid=1225&typeid=17432&typeid=17433&typeid=1223&typeid=17428&typeid=17429&typeid=22&typeid=17425&typeid=17426&typeid=11396&typeid=17869&typeid=17870&typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=40&typeid=39&typeid=11399&regionlimit=10000048';
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file($urlPlacid);
    }

    /**
     * @param $typeID
     * @return bool|string String value if $typeID is found, FALSE on error
     */
    public function getSellMinByType($typeID) {

        $result = $this->xml->xpath("/*/marketstat/type[@id = '$typeID']/sell/min");
        if (!$result) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return (string)$result[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a function. Now the reason that I have $urlPlacid is because I also have $urlForge and $urlUniverse. I'm incredibly new to php so please excuse my ignorance. How would I build these other url's into the function, and then go about calling it differently for each one? Essentailly, each typeID gets three different values due to which URL is used against it

Comment: Well you can make that class accepting the URL in the constructor function as a parameter. When you instantiate it with `new`, you pass it along, for example: `$statsPlacid = new EveCentralMarketstat($urlPlacid);` or similar. You can also just pass the name and store the urls inside, select by the name. Additionally depending on how many operations you do with that request, you might want to fetch all Ids at once for all three types.

Comment: I hope it gains you some ISKs. Whenever I'll re-activate my account I'll search you online ;)

Comment: haha, thanks. Currently working on a relatively simple script that allows users to enter their max mining yeild and what they have mined, and based on the current rates of the various locations it automatically sets a rate for the corporation to buy back. I'm fairly certain there is already software that does this, but I'm using this as a learning experience

Comment: would I then in the construct have the three $urlPlacid/Forge/Universe followed by, isntead of $this, $xmlPlacid/forge/universe. Then in the function `getSellMinByType` pass in ($typeID) however this is where my brain stops. How would I return the three values and differentiate between them?

Comment: Yes, that is a good question. I'd say it depends how you want to get the values. And the I would write the access class to offer a nice function for that. Now I see that those are regions. I compile you a small example.

Comment: edited original question. In the "old form" I have three foreach statements for each $url. And within that I update the table. That can't be the most efficient way of doing that with the functions, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22070/discussion-between-mhopkins321-and-hakre)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a node by ID just use xpath
`$node = $xmlPlacid->xpath("//*[@id='foo']");`

Answer (score 1):

You missed `==` equal to operator in `IF`

```
if($type['id'] == $oldTypeID){
...
}
```

Comment: it's always something easy isn't it? I'll give you the check in 7 minutes when the timer is up. Thanks